# jlink compression plugin performance penalty

Tags: java, java-module, jlink, java-17

What is the performance penalty like for using the compression plugin to create a smaller java runtime image? I know it exists but testing separate builds of my application I could find no perceptible difference between the compressed and uncompressed versions.

Comment: Do you mean the `0`, `1`, or `2` specified to `--compress=`?

Comment: @holger Not exactly,  I mean how do you roughly calculate the performance hit your app takes. Like what processor speed, lib count, lib size, etc even matters.

Comment: My question was, which option(s) are you talking about. Are these three options the alternatives you want to compare?

Comment: @Holger My apologies, totally misinterpreted your comment. As I don't have any real insight to how the compression works I don't have any specific requirements for a specific option. Option 2 would probably be of the most interest since (AFAIK) it should provide the most compression. But any insight into the practical performance trade offs would be an acceptable answer.

Comment: I have not the time to write a large answer now, but in general, compression does not necessarily imply a performance penalty at all. The data has to be loaded or transferred from a cache first, an operation that scales with the size of the data, so the savings at this point can compensate the higher processing requirements, especially with modern CPUs which can calculate far faster than the RAM transfer speed. The `--compress=2` does similar things as the jar compression, which you might use anyway when not using linked module images, so it’s the same processing speed you’re used to.